# How to allocate more RAM when using RStudio (R version 4.3.0)?

Tags: r, performance, rstudio, ram

When I run some calculations with R 4.3.0 which take time, I observe that R uses maximum 8GB of RAM.
However, I have a computer with 32GB of RAM available :

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM   32.0 GB (31.8 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Is there any way to increase the limit and take full advantage of the PC performance?

Previously, I had 4 sticks of 8GB each and I replaced these sticks by a single one of 32GB.
I thought that R limits RAM memory to one stick but it's not the case obviously.
After replacing RAM sticks by a single one, I also tried to reinstall R, RStudio and dependecies but nothing work.
I also tried to modify the allocated memory size in Windows cmd (see printscreen below) but it doesn't work. Maybe it's wrong what I try to do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM5mt.png)
Do you have other solutions to suggest?